# Remove Text Wrap When Image Floats Left Inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="left-image-right-text">
   <p>
    <img src="someimage.png">
    Some text.
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-image-right-text img {
float: left;
padding: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

However, this causes the text to wrap underneath the image. How do I not allow the text to wrap underneath and be its own separate column from the image?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use flexbox:

```css
.left-image-right-text {
  display:flex;
  padding:0 100px;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-image-right-text">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=1069"> Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't use float though.

Comment: @damian1225 yes because the issue is the float :)

Answer (score 1):

you can put your text inside  like this

```
<span class="text-class"> Some text. Some Text. Some Text</span>
```

and then set span display as table-cell

```css
.left-image-right-text img {
float: left;
padding: 0 50px 50px 0;

}

.text-class{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-image-right-text">
   <p>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=1069">
    <span class="text-class">Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some text.
              Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some Some text.
       Some text.
          Some text.   Some text.   Some text.
          </span>
   </p>
</div>
```